# How to determine whether Blu-ray disc is HTL or LTH?

Tags: burning, blu-ray, optical-media

With a blank Blu-ray disc inserted into a Blu-ray burner drive, how can I determine whether the disc is HTL or LTH?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this, but if you look at the sources of a public-domain blu-ray recorder like [cdrecord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtools/) you should find what you want.

Comment: @AFH As to "why", manufacturers' product labels and marketing do not often display this information. The HTL manufacturing technique uses only inorganic materials, and HTL media has more longevity because it is not susceptible to deterioration of an organic dye. It is important to know this before using the media for a long-term archive.

Comment: I understand the different longevity, but surely you need to know this when you purchase your media?

Comment: @AFH, but sadly it's hardly ever disclosed in the product listing or label :(

Comment: You're absolutely right: I checked my stock of blanks, and I am amazed to find no identification. There is an almost unreadable batch number on the disc itself, and I could not find any data when I googled parts of it. I have found that some products such as [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RECORDABLE-Inkjet-Printable-Packs-Spindle/dp/B001MYQM00) declare their type, so I guess that gives you a start. If you already have media in stock, then Aprel's answer looks good, though I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the best way I've found:

1. Determine the manufacturer code and media type of the media. On Linux, I used [`cdrecord`](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html)`dev=XXX -atip | grep -i 'manufacturer\|media type'`, where `XXX` is the code for the Blu-ray burner as listed by `cdrecord -scanbus`.
2. Look up the manufacturer and media type codes at http://www.blu-raydisc.info/licensee-list/discmanuid-licenseelist.php . The table on that site identifies "recording type" (i.e. HTL or LTH) and also write speed from these codes.

Answer (score 3):

With image burning software. [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) forinstance.

In Imgburn main menu just click on anything writing related. For example, "Write image file to disc"

Now a new window pops up

Please check that you have the correct burner selected in the left hand side, if you have more than one disc burner.

Scroll down on the right pane, and you find the info under "Recorded Mark Polarity"

In august 2016 it looked like this: [ImgBurn Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UafIy.png)